# Including GLSL files in project pane in a QTCreator CMake project

Tags: cmake, glsl, qt-creator

I am working through the OpenGL tutorial here: [OpenGL-Tutorial.org](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/), and want to use QTCreator and CMake to build the examples.

Opening the root `CMakeLists.txt` file opens the project, which then builds/runs correctly (after following instructions on the website), but the fragment and vertex files do not show up in the projects pane. I have tried renaming them to `.frag`, `.vert` and `.glsl` with no effect. If I drag these files from a folder they open in the edit pane with correct syntax highlighting.

How do I get these files to show up in the projects pane?

---

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and have tried QTCreator from packages and the newest source on sourceforge.

Comment: They probably aren't supposed to. They're loaded and compiled at runtime; they shouldn't be part of the project itself.

Comment: In case anyone else comes here - I used GLFW, which is ace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
file(GLOB RES_FILES *.frag *.vert *.glsl)

add_executable(exe_name ${RES_FILES} ${C/CPP FILES})
```

Comment: +1 or file(GLOB_RECURSE RES_FILES *.frag *.vert *.glsl) add_executable(exe_name ${RES_FILES}) if your shader files are not in your cmakelist.txt folder and you aren't add regular source files.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to include shader files in your Qt project using Cmake is through the CMake command `qt5_add_resources`. [One of the Qt's examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-cube-example.html) does the same when using qmake. For my application I found it to be more practical to include the shader files as resources.

So, for this, you would have to prepare a resource file, for example, `Shaders.qrc`, and add there all the shader files you want to use, e.g.:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>Stroke.frag</file>
        <file>Stroke.geom</file>
        <file>Stroke.vert</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then in the `CMakeLists.txt`, add the resource file:

```
qt5_add_resources(SHADER_RSC_ADDED 
    Shaders/Shaders.qrc
)
```

And add it to the executable (or library):

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${PROJECT_SRCS}
    ${SHADER_RSC_ADDED}
)
```

After re-build, the project tree will look like below:

[image: Added shaders as qrc file]

Answer (score 0):

You can add the shader files as other files in the `.pro`  file.

```
OTHER_FILES += \
    simple.frag \
    simple.vert
```

Also you should consider using the QT resource management for your shader files. I have recently created a simple OpenGL 3.2 example project in Qt, which also shows how to use the Qt for resource management of shader files. The project is available here: https://github.com/mortennobel/QtOpenGL3.2Core

Warning: the project is only tested on Windows and OS/X.

Comment: I don't have a .pro file as I am using CMake to compile the program, rather than qmake.